# Choosing checkbox over toggle switch for focus order?

Tags: toggle

[image: Plan A and PlanB]

Should I choose a checkbox over a toggle switch due to focus order? I personally prefer Option B because it's less eye catching than A, and I know a toggle switch is a metaphor for turning something on or off, but in this context, I'd like to make the user focus more on the start button since it's the more important and users have to click it to start a program.

My concern is that the toggle switch would draw the user's attention and harm usability.

Comment: [Checkbox vs Toggle Switch: 7 Use-Cases of Forms Design](https://uxplanet.org/checkbox-vs-toggle-switch-7fc6e83f10b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are fine. To give the start and stop functions a better focus you could set the toggle or check box a different location (maybe on the right side)

If you use the switch you should change the wording to something like 'show debug info' instead of 'debug info on'. Other wise the wording could be mistaken as a state of the switch.

When Debug is checked, running the program will show users extra messages like text or pictures to help solve problems.
[image]

Comment: What if my screen is 1080P, the debug info settings would on the far right on the window.Will that affect  usability？My answer is no tho.

Answer (score 0):

Having only three commands, I don't see any need to mix icon actions with checkboxes or toggles. I would try to seek coherence by unifying criteria, the simplest way is three icons:

[image]

Comment: it sounds reasonable too，that's an inspiring idea!Thank you

Comment: Problem is start and stop affect each other (only one can be active). Debug is completely separate from either, so it doesn't seem intuitive to mix the logic up by making them look the same. @BrunoH seems more correct in his approach to separate them.

Comment: it's fine actually，when u click debug or run, only stop button is available.In another word,There will not be two buttons that are activated at the same time